# Compiling a C# .NET Application with a Google Voice API

Tags: c#, .net, api, voice

So from scouring the internet I managed to find an apparently working "Google Voice API". Which is great! I'm working on an application that detects when a server process crashes / errors out and then notifies me through text. It'd be really useful because the server isn't totally reliable and on occasion needs a reset and sometimes I'm too lazy to get off my ass from the couch / busy doing something else.

Anyway, the API:

http://sourceforge.net/projects/gvoicedotnet/

I added the dll as a reference and everything loaded up well with intellisense. I added the dll into my .cs (using `using` [haha]). After everything was added I decided to compile just to make sure it would compile, and of course it didn't.

The Error:

> Error 201 The type or namespace name 'Google' could not be found (are
>   you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)

Anyway, for some reason at every compile it removes the dll as a reference? The only thing that seems to be somewhat of an indicator (which I doubt is involved) is this warning

> The referenced assembly "Google.Voice.Service, Version=1.0.0.0,
>   Culture=neutral, processorArchitecture=MSIL" could not be resolved
>   because it has a dependency on "System.Web, Version=4.0.0.0,
>   Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b03f5f7f11d50a3a" which is not in the
>   currently targeted framework
>   ".NETFramework,Version=v4.0,Profile=Client". Please remove references
>   to assemblies not in the targeted framework or consider retargeting
>   your project.

**tl;dr** reference keeps automatically becoming unreferenced.

Comment: Can you possibly post some Code?

Comment: What version of you the .NET framework is your application compiled with?

Comment: System.Web doesn't work with 4 Client Profile. Change the build to 4.0 Full

Comment: I don't understand "(using using [haha])".  Why the haha?

Comment: because referenced it, using the keyword using.... sorry stupid humor

Comment: don't worry @ksandarusi I thought it was funny :)

Comment: any final solution with full source code sample ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to change your target framework to the full .Net 4 framework and then add a reference to System.Web.

Comment: Ah Ok, yeah I was wondering why I had a client profile. If I have extended can I just add that (This stuff should have been installed when I installed visual studio which is why I'm asking.)

Comment: Yes, you should be able to change the target framework. Do you know how to do that?

Comment: You are welcome, and welcome to stackoverflow. Keep in mind that if an answer solves or helps you solve your question, you should click on the checkmark next to that answer so that future visitors to the question know this is what fixed your issue.